# Background Color is affecting box-shadow

Tags: html, css

So here's my problem: I have a big container div, and a div inside that container. the container has a box-shadow on it that is black. When I set the inner div's background color to black, you can't see the box-shadow. I thought maybe this was an illusion caused by the eye, but taking a closer look you can see the pixel differentiation.
[Example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBnmn.png)

Here is a more clear depiction of the problem:
[Yet another example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZBMz.png)

Raw code incoming!

HTML: (The div#footerContainer part is pretty much the important part)

```
<div id="bodyContainer">
<div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="menuElements" class="center">
        <a href="#"><div class="menuElement underlineHover" color="#FF0E0E">Home</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="menuElement underlineHover" color="#13DB13">Services</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="menuElement underlineHover" color="#1792BB">Photo Gallery</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="menuElement underlineHover" color="#E4146B">Why Use Fox Foliage?</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="menuElement underlineHover" color="#FF9616">Contact</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="barSpacer" style="margin: 0 auto 20px"></div>
<div id="imageContainer">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg"/>
    <div id="title">
        <div class="center">
            <p class="spaced">Fox Foliage</p>|<p class="spaced">352-949-2481</p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="barSpacer"></div>
<div id="contentContainer">
    <?php include("content.php") ?>
</div>
<div id="barSpacer"></div>
<div id="footerContainer">

</div>
```

CSS (Container DIV):

```
div#bodyContainer{
max-width: 1000px;
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px 2px black;
```

}

CSS (Footer DIV):

```
div#footerContainer {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: white;
```

}

The whole goal is to make sure the box-shadow is the same consistency all the way around.

Comment: Huh? You're bothered by a black box-shadow not showing on a black element? Am I misunderstanding? What do you expect to happen when you place black on top of black?

Comment: If you look closely you can see the black line of pixels halts at the footer element. If I put a box shadow on the footer element it shows up but of course goes all the way around the footer element which is not the desired effect.

Comment: try to give it another background color than black. Will you see it?

Comment: When using the color orange, the orange appear much darker all around the white. Around the black it's much brighter. I resorted to using the color picker extension for chrome and it shows that here is a discoloration between white and black areas of the box-shadow

Comment: I think you're merely experiencing an optical illusion. The black shadow will always appear darker against a light background. The edge gets less defined visually when you put the black shadow against a black fill, but it's still there. This "discoloration" you are alluding to is most probably due to the *transparency* in the shadow itself.

Comment: I figured the same thing until using the color picker confirming that there are two totally different hues of the same color showing when put next to white or black.

Comment: Again. shadows have transparency so underlying colors *will* alter the hues. And... your'e assuming whatever extension you are using is always accurate as well.

Comment: When comparing the two areas on a white canvas even, the difference is still visible. And you can make sure a color picker is working simply by checking any constant color.